# Calling class attribute without creating an instance to that class

Tags: python

I would like to initialize a class, then call an attribute which was set during the initialization, but without creating another instance. As a test example:

```
class t1:
    def __init__(self, skipInit=False):
        if not skipInit:
            print 'Initialized'
            self.var = 123456
        else:
            print 'Not Initialized'

    def returnVar(self):
        return self.var

class t2:
    def getVar(self):
        print t1.returnVar(t1)
```

I want to initialize t1 with `t1()`, and later on, access to *var* from t2, with `t2.getVar(t2)` or some other way from within t2. Obviously the above code is not working, and I have a hard time understanding why.

In actuality the classes are in a wxPython program. There is a Frame->Notebook->Panel->MenuBar hierarchy, all in separate files. I set a number of variables during the Panel initialization, and try to access these from one of the menu items on the GUI. At that point panel will already be initialized and shown, which why I added the skipInit switch. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Well, that doesnt make much sense. Are you aware of the differenec between clases and instances? `self.var` is a instance attribute, not creating it sometimes would defeat the purpose of a class. Maybe a concrete example would explain better what you want. It seems you could just write a function that does the initialization and you call it just once ...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The instance `self.var` must be set during initialization, and accessed later on without initializing again. In short, I cannot modify `t1` above. So how can I access the instance `t1.var` without initializing t1 again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing called `t1.var`, so of course you can't access it. `var` is an attribute of a `t1` *instance;* it doesn't exist on the class. Since you can have any number of instances of `t1`, there's no way for an instance method of `t2` to know *which* `t1` instance it should look for the attribute `var` in without you *telling it.* You can do this when you instantiate `t2`.

```
# t1 class is the same as yours

class t2:
    def __init__(self, t1):
        self.t1 = t1
    def getVar(self):
        print self.t1.returnVar(t1)

obj1 = t1()
obj2 = t2(obj1)  # give the t2 instance the t1 instance

print obj2.getVar()
```

Comment: I get it now! Thanks a lot, especially for the explanation. In the actual wx program I ended up naming the instances, like obj1 above, and passed them as args to the menubar child. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, then you just need to pass your instance of t1 to an instance of t2.

```
class t2:
    def getVar(self, t1):
        print t1.returnVar(t1)

t1_instance = t1()
t2_instance = t2()

t2.getVar(t1_instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
class T1(object):   # Subclassing object makes a new-style class
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 123456

t1 = T1()
# t1 is now an instance of T1. This calls __init__ to set it up.

print t1.var        # 123456
```

Comment: I wish... `print t1.var` must be in a different class, which creates my problem. Also please see my comment above.

Comment: @Murat: So that other class needs to have a reference to your `t1` instance, not the class (which I've called `T1`).